# JS variable into TWIG template

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, symfony6

I'm working on a restaurant website with symfony 6.2 and I have to do a reservation page. On this page I'm using [easepick](https://easepick.com/) to pick the date.

**My question is** : How can I get the date data from JS into TWIG to compare with my DB date data ?

Here I got the date picked when selected :

```
picker.on("select", () => {
  let pickerDate = picker.getDate();
  console.log(pickerDate);
});
```

As a first step to the final purpose, I'm trying to display only the booked ones of the selected day

Here is what I'm looking for but **pickerDate** is obviously not recognized :

```
{% for reservation in reservationTime %}
  {% if pickerDate is same as(reservation.datetime | date)  %}

    <li class="mx-1 my-1"><a class="btn btn-danger">{{ reservation.datetime | format_time('short') }}</a></li>

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The final purpose is to show all the available time.
I don't even know if it's possible/deprecated

Comment: you can't get that JS variable/value into twig without submitting a form which means a re-render of the page (unless its ajax). twig is rendered on the server. JS runs in the user's browser. it's not possible to pick a date via a datepicker and then do a `for` loop via twig.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! So what are my options to get the date data and compare it to the DB ? 
AJAX ? 
Passing the data to PHP First then TWIG ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to resort to ajax to pass the variables to PHP. You could indeed return HTML by rendering a template based on the variables